# Xcode Pushing GIT to Visual Studio Team Service

Tags: xcode, git, azure-devops

We're learning about and setting up source control with Visual Studio Team Services.
We have one Mac XCode project want to add to the source control, but I can't figure out how to do it.

According to this: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/share-your-code-in-git-xcode We should be able to set it up as a remote repository, and then just push to it, but when I try I get this error:

> The source control operation failed because the URL http://project.visualstudio.com/_git/myprojectname%20IOS" cannont be used with Git. Make sure the URL is valid and try again.

It never asked for a password or anything, so I don't know if I just have a permission set up incorrectly somewhere?

Comment: Not sure why the drive by down vote...

Comment: What's the result if there isn't whitespace included in project/repository name?

Comment: @starain-MSFT That solved it! Now I gotta try to figure out how to delete the project with the space in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The space was the problem. Created a new project without the space and it popped up asking for the alternative credentials for the project.